# Spring Batch Multi Line record PatternMatch BeanList

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a file with record spread across multiple lines to be processed in spring batch.

```
Begin
EXP 123 1026
EXP 456 9894
INC 076 2014 1231
INC 187 2013 1045
End
```

The first three characters are used to identify the type of record. I am using PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer to map the records to the bean. How to create a list for EXP and INC where the list for EXP will have all the EXP records and the INC list will have all INC records?

Comment: I had to retract my "close" vote because I want to understand better one thing: are EXP and INC records related with some parent/child relationships? Do you want to save all EXP and INC records at the same time (as a big chunk)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [spring-batch-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples). In particular, the [Multiline example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#multiline)

You can find the [multilineJob.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/multilineJob.xml) in the src/main/resources/jobs, along with all the other example job xml files.

You're going to need to implement a few of your own components. In particular some kind of aggregating reader to which you'll need to pass it a delegate reader. You can check out from the sample, the [AggregateItemReader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java). What you can do is create a wrapper class to hold two lists, one for EXP and one for INC objects. For each item read, either add the line/object to the EXP list or the INC list in the wrapper.

All the custom classes in the example are in `org.springframework.batch.sample.domain`  sub-packages. You should be able to extract them and run the example.